# Backup Sharepoint Server site and restore onto Sharepoint Foundation

Tags: 2010, backup

I do not know the below is possible...

We have a Production environment that has Sharepoint Server 2010 and a Test Environment that has Sharepoint Foundation 2010.

I would like to do one test on the Sharepoint Foundation environment. However, I need the data from the Sharepoint Server Production Environment.

Would it be possible to transfer the data from the Sharepoint Production Environment? If I create a site backup using the Server environment. Can I restore it onto the foundation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is **not** recommended, you can't restore a site back-up from SharePoint Server to SharePoint Foundation.

Restoring a site collection from SharePoint Server to SharePoint Foundation involves difference of Features set that SharePoint offer in different versions for e.g.

> Standard and Enterprise vs Foundation features

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Do you think there is another approach rather than a site backup to restore the data please?

Comment: You can upgrade your test environment from Foundation to the latest patches level to SharePoint Server, in Production environment, then try to take the Content DB back from production and try attaching to your test environment.